# Error Argument 1: cannot convert from int[*,*] to 'int'

Tags: c#

When i try to display the item from the array it brings up this:

> Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from int[*,*] to 'int'.

```
CountOddNumbersV1(tabel));


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i, j;

    Console.WriteLine("Introduceti numarul de linii:");
    int l = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Introduceti numarul de coloane:");
    int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[,] tabel = new int[l, c];

    Console.WriteLine("Introduceti elementele matricii:");

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("A[{0}][{1}]=", i, j);
            tabel[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Masivul {0}", String.Join(", ", tabel));
    Console.WriteLine("Masivul contine {0} numere impare ", CountOddNumbersV1(tabel));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static int CountOddNumbersV1(params int[] values)
{
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        int number = values[i];

        if (IsOdd(number))
        {
            result++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

static bool IsOdd(int i)
{
    return i % 2 != 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory. You're trying to pass `tabel` (which is of type `int[,]`) to the `CountOddNumbersV1` method (which expects an argument of type `int[]`), and the error is telling you that there is no automatic conversion between these two types.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error message is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Array `int[] values` in `CountOddNumbersV1` method and `int[,] tabel` are different array types, with different dimensions count.